# Using Semantic merge as diff tool in Perforce

Tags: perforce, semantic-merge

I'm trying to set up [SemanticMerge](http://www.semanticmerge.com/) as my diff tool for C# in Perforce.

I've configured perforce with the exe and with the arguments `-s=%1 -d=%2 -l=csharp`

[image: diff tool settings]

But when I try to diff a C# file I receive the error:

> Could not find file c:\Program Files Perforce\%1

[image: error message]

The selected file is not in that location (nor is its filename %1)...

I am no doubt being slow and am trying to RTFM but am also hoping someone here can see what I'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [user on twitter](https://twitter.com/miryamgsm/status/362585407013134337) pointed me at a PDF which I can't believe I hadn't previously managed to find

http://www.semanticmerge.com/documents/SemanticMerge-Perforce.pdf

In short it's necessary to create a batch file to launch external diff and merge tools in Perforce.

Comment: According to https://www.semanticmerge.com/documentation/main.shtml#HowtoconfigurewithPerforce the batch file is no longer required as of Nov 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Using equal in the arguments `-s=%1 -d=%2` will prevent the interpretation of `%1` and `%2` as file paths, hence your weird error. `semanticmergetool` also accepts arguments with space: `-s "$LOCAL" -d "$REMOTE"` and positional arguments: `"$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"`, so you can set for instance:

```
Preferences > Diff > Default diff application: Other application
Location: .../semanticmerge/semanticmergetool.exe
Arguments: %1 %2
```

To set `semanticmerge` as merge tool, use `Arguments: %1 %2 %b %r`

Reference:
https://users.semanticmerge.com/documentation/how-to-configure/semanticmerge-configuration-guide.shtml#HowtoconfigurewithPerforce